# VBO with and without shaders OpenGL C++

Tags: opengl, vbo

Im trying to implement modern OpenGL, but the problem is: most tutorials are based on 3.3+, and talk about GLSL 330, I only have GLSL 130. Therefore, many things are apparently different, since my VBO's do not work.

Could you give me general hints or a tutorial that explains how to use GLSL 130 with VBO's? In my case, I have the vbo loaded, but when I use my shader program, only vertices called with glVertex get rendered, it's like the vbo gets ignored (no input). How to solve this?

And can you use VBO's without shaders? I tried to do that, but it crashed...

Comment: VBOs and shaders (and shader versions) are completely orthogonal features in the GL. (Modern GL just requires both.) What makes you think that "your VBOs dont work", just because you use GLSL 1.30 instead of 3.30?

Comment: As I said, they are new for me, so I followed tutorials, but most tutorials (or all I found) are for 330 GLSL. For instance, layout (=0) or sth doesnt exist in 130, and gl_modelview_matrix etc. probably do not exist in 330. I simply do not know where to start...

Comment: you mix up a lot of different things.

Comment: Unfortunately, this aspect of programming OpenGL right now is a complete mess for people trying to learn things. It's completely understandable that you're confused because it is a confusing situation. Do you have the option of upgrading to newer drivers or a newer OS that would work with 3.3+?

Comment: Im using NVIDIA and I can update my drivers, however Im afraid my computer does not have support for 330+ GLSL. This is bad luck, since GLSL 330+ is the apparently the modern standard

Answer (score 3):

Yes, VBOs can still be used in GLSL 130, and can still be used even without shaders.  The purpose of the VBO is to hold the vertex attributes for drawing.  Most up to date tutorials I've seen have you use the layout position specifier for indicating how to address the different attributes in your shader, i.e.

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 Position;
```

This isn't supported in GLSL 130, so you have to have another way of relating the attribute with the VBO.  It's pretty simple... you can use [`glBindAttribLocation`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml) or [`glGetAttribLocation`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetAttribLocation.xml).  Calling `glGetAttribLocation` will give you the identifier you need to use in `glVertexAttribPointer` to associate the VBO data with the particular attribute.  You can call this at any time after the program has been compiled.  In addition, you can call glBindAttribLocation to specifically set the identifier that will be associated with a given attribute name if you call it after you've created the program object but before you link the shaders.  This is handy because it lets you decide for yourself what the location should be, just as you would be able to with the layout specifier.

Finally, if you want to use a VBO without using a shader at all, then you still have to find a way of associating the data in the VBO with the various inputs that the fixed function pipeline expects.  This is done using a now deprecated method called `glEnableClientState()`  and `glVertexPointer()`, which together let you tell OpenGL what fixed function pipeline attribute you're going to populate, and how it can find the data in the VBO.

Comment: You actually do not have to call `glVertexPointer (...)`, `glVertexAttribPointer (0, ...)` is guaranteed to alias to vertex position in the fixed-function pipeline. `glVertexPointer` is definitely the better way to go though, because people who do not know this will be confused by code that sets vertex attribute 0 pointer in a fixed-function application.

Comment: I'm curious where that's documented and if the other fixed function vertex attributes have standard aliases.

Comment: If you take a look at the [OpenGL 4.4 ***compatibility*** profile](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.compatibility.pdf) specification, on pg. 387 under the sub-section **"10.8.2 Transferring Vertices With Vertex Attribute Zero"** in ugly red (deprecated) text, it describes this behavior. This only (portably) applies to vertex attribute **0**, but before GLSL was introduced into core (GL 2.0) the [ARB Vertex Program extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_program.txt) defined an entire set of aliases under **Table X.1**. They are not ***supposed*** to work in GLSL.

Comment: Am I supposed to use deprecated functionality now I do not have support for 330 GLSL? I namely aim to write an engine able to run on most OpenGL implementations, so I could start with <330. The strange thing is, if I use VBO and glvertex in one function, the only thing my shader renders is the glvertex, not the VBO given vertices. Does this have to do with BindAttribLocation?

Comment: You can't combine the use of glVertex() and a VBO (and you can't use glBegin()/glEnd() either, you need to be using glDrawElements() or glDrawArrays() ).  Using the VBO with the fixed function pipeline is mostly a matter of calling glEnableClientState() so that OpenGL knows to pull vertices from the VBO and then using the glDrawArrays() method to force the pipeline to start churning through your triangles.